# Sending multiple parameters to a method in C#?

Tags: c#, parameters

Sending multiple parameters to a method?

So, i am pretty new to C# and Visual Studio and i am "learning by doing" and asking questions. I am writing a small Windows Form application.

I am trying to send another form values.

I have a list of objects from this class:

```
class Cars
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Color { get; private set; }

    public Cars(string name, string color)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Color = color;
    }
 }
```

So in my Form1 i have access to these objects by using:

```
List<Cars> cars = new List<Cars>();
```

This list of Cars is loaded in other methods.

So now, i am trying to send another form (Edit form) a car.
I would like to do this:

```
var form2 = new frmEdit(cars[0]);
```

But then compiler complains about that i need to set my class to public...bad OOP. So then i could do it like this:

```
var form2 = new frmEdit(cars[0].Name,cars[0].Color);
```

Fine! But if this was another language like Javascript or PHP i would have sent an object. So i have read about "Anonymus Types" in C# so i thought that could be a good solution.

But the receiveing form doesn´t know about that...so it will complain if i use it like this:

```
car.Name;
```

So what should i do here? I am trying to use at least "some" good OOP so i think it is a bad solution making the Cars class public. The Edit form does not need to know about the Cars class.

Thank you for any advice!

[EDIT]
Edit form constructor:

```
public frmEdit(string name, string color)
{
textName.Text = name;
textColor.Text = color;
}
```

Comment: can you add your frmEdit constructor?

Comment: You can send `dynamic`. But why do you reject static type checking? Where did you read about that good OOP?

Comment: Why not make Car internal?

Comment: Why would making the Cars class public bad OOP?

Comment: @Yuriy N I don´t reject anything. I don´t know about "dynamic".

Comment: @Stuart Internal to frmEdit? No, Why would i do that? FrmMain handles the class.

Comment: @Gimly, Encapsulation.

Comment: `internal`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/internal

Comment: @Juw, no internal says it's visible to other classes within the same assembly. You need to look up the access modifiers public / private / internal. You seem to be against making it public, presumably because you don't want it to be public outside your assembly. Internal fixes this, if that's your concern.

Comment: @Juw, in this case using dynamic would be crazy.

Comment: @Juw, I don't think you understand what encapuslation is. Making a class public in no way breaks encapsulation.

Comment: Your edit form does need to know a bit about the Cars class, if it is supposed to *edit* a Cars instance. You may however want to use a `CarViewModel` that exposes *just* the properties that that form needs to know about.

Comment: @Juw as Stuart says, encapsulation doesn't mean you can't make anything public, especially classes. Encapsulation means you shouldn't leak implementation details to users of your classes by restricting direct access to some object's components.

Comment: @HansKesting, The edit form does not change anything in the instance. It just takes the text and send it back to the MainForm....the MainForm handles changing of the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your frmEdit to:

```
private Cars myCar; // add this var.

public frmEdit(Cars car)
{
     this.myCar = car; // now you have your car stored if you need
     textName.Text = car.Name;
     textColor.Text = car.Color;
}
```

And Then:

```
var form2 = new frmEdit(cars[0]);
```